# How to add all dictionaries up, and conduct a new dictionay?

Tags: python, dictionary

There are 8 dictionaries on 'datagather', I wanna add them up and conduct the new dictionary 'results'

As my code shows:

```
for countres in datagather:
    #print (countres)
    for key in counts:
        results[key]+=countres[key]
```

In datagather, if run `print (countres)` , the results will be:

```
{'other': 107, 'C4': 1, 'C3': 1, 'A2': 1, 'D3': 1, 'A3': 0, 'C5': 0, 'B3': 2, 'A1': 0, 'B4': 0, 'A4': 0, 'D5': 0, 'B1': 2, 'C1': 1, 'D4': 0, 'B2': 3, 'C2': 7}
{'other': 109, 'C4': 0, 'C3': 3, 'A2': 0, 'D3': 0, 'A3': 1, 'C5': 0, 'B3': 1, 'A1': 0, 'D5': 0, 'A4': 0, 'B4': 1, 'B1': 2, 'C1': 0, 'D4': 0, 'B2': 3, 'C2': 7}
{'other': 116, 'C4': 1, 'C3': 2, 'A2': 0, 'D3': 0, 'A3': 0, 'B4': 0, 'B3': 1, 'C5': 0, 'A1': 0, 'D5': 0, 'A4': 0, 'B1': 0, 'C1': 0, 'D4': 0, 'B2': 3, 'C2': 1}
{'other': 104, 'C4': 0, 'C3': 3, 'A2': 0, 'D3': 1, 'A3': 0, 'C5': 0, 'B3': 2, 'A1': 0, 'B4': 1, 'A4': 0, 'D5': 1, 'B1': 1, 'C1': 0, 'D4': 0, 'B2': 3, 'C2': 7}
{'other': 108, 'C4': 2, 'C3': 2, 'A2': 0, 'D3': 1, 'A3': 0, 'C5': 0, 'B3': 0, 'A1': 0, 'D5': 0, 'A4': 0, 'B4': 0, 'B1': 0, 'C1': 0, 'D4': 0, 'B2': 6, 'C2': 7}
{'other': 105, 'C4': 0, 'C3': 1, 'A2': 0, 'D3': 0, 'A3': 0, 'C5': 0, 'B3': 1, 'A1': 0, 'B4': 0, 'A4': 0, 'D5': 0, 'B1': 2, 'C1': 0, 'D4': 1, 'B2': 4, 'C2': 9}
{'other': 109, 'C4': 1, 'C3': 0, 'A2': 0, 'D3': 1, 'A3': 0, 'C5': 1, 'B3': 0, 'A1': 0, 'D5': 0, 'A4': 0, 'B4': 0, 'B1': 0, 'C1': 0, 'D4': 1, 'B2': 6, 'C2': 7}
{'other': 104, 'C4': 2, 'C3': 3, 'A2': 1, 'D3': 0, 'A3': 1, 'C5': 0, 'B3': 1, 'A1': 0, 'D5': 0, 'A4': 0, 'B4': 0, 'B1': 0, 'C1': 0, 'D4': 0, 'B2': 8, 'C2': 5}
```

They all have the same 'key' and different values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a couple options, I think `Counter` is the prettiest.

### Use `defaultdict`

```
import collections
results = collections.defaultdict(int)
for di in datagather:
    for key in di:
        results[key] += di[key]
print(dict(results))
```

## Use `Counter`:

```
import collections
results = collections.Counter()
for di in datagather:
    results.update(di)
print(dict(results))
```

## Finally, you could write your own without `collections`

```
results = {}
for di in datagather:
    for key in di:
        if key in results:
            results[key] += di[key]
        else:
            results[key] = di[key]
print(results)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Counter` object in `collections`, which is a *dictionary-like* object that will sum on update.

```
from collections import Counter
counters = (
    {'other': 107, 'C4': 1, 'C3': 1, 'A2': 1, 'D3': 1, 'A3': 0, 'C5': 0, 'B3': 2, 'A1': 0, 'B4': 0, 'A4': 0, 'D5': 0, 'B1': 2, 'C1': 1, 'D4': 0, 'B2': 3, 'C2': 7},
    {'other': 109, 'C4': 0, 'C3': 3, 'A2': 0, 'D3': 0, 'A3': 1, 'C5': 0, 'B3': 1, 'A1': 0, 'D5': 0, 'A4': 0, 'B4': 1, 'B1': 2, 'C1': 0, 'D4': 0, 'B2': 3, 'C2': 7},
    {'other': 116, 'C4': 1, 'C3': 2, 'A2': 0, 'D3': 0, 'A3': 0, 'B4': 0, 'B3': 1, 'C5': 0, 'A1': 0, 'D5': 0, 'A4': 0, 'B1': 0, 'C1': 0, 'D4': 0, 'B2': 3, 'C2': 1},
    {'other': 104, 'C4': 0, 'C3': 3, 'A2': 0, 'D3': 1, 'A3': 0, 'C5': 0, 'B3': 2, 'A1': 0, 'B4': 1, 'A4': 0, 'D5': 1, 'B1': 1, 'C1': 0, 'D4': 0, 'B2': 3, 'C2': 7},
    {'other': 108, 'C4': 2, 'C3': 2, 'A2': 0, 'D3': 1, 'A3': 0, 'C5': 0, 'B3': 0, 'A1': 0, 'D5': 0, 'A4': 0, 'B4': 0, 'B1': 0, 'C1': 0, 'D4': 0, 'B2': 6, 'C2': 7},
    {'other': 105, 'C4': 0, 'C3': 1, 'A2': 0, 'D3': 0, 'A3': 0, 'C5': 0, 'B3': 1, 'A1': 0, 'B4': 0, 'A4': 0, 'D5': 0, 'B1': 2, 'C1': 0, 'D4': 1, 'B2': 4, 'C2': 9},
    {'other': 109, 'C4': 1, 'C3': 0, 'A2': 0, 'D3': 1, 'A3': 0, 'C5': 1, 'B3': 0, 'A1': 0, 'D5': 0, 'A4': 0, 'B4': 0, 'B1': 0, 'C1': 0, 'D4': 1, 'B2': 6, 'C2': 7},
    {'other': 104, 'C4': 2, 'C3': 3, 'A2': 1, 'D3': 0, 'A3': 1, 'C5': 0, 'B3': 1, 'A1': 0, 'D5': 0, 'A4': 0, 'B4': 0, 'B1': 0, 'C1': 0, 'D4': 0, 'B2': 8, 'C2': 5})

c = Counter()
for d in counters:
    c.update(d)
```

Result:

```
Counter({'A1': 0,
         'A2': 2,
         'A3': 2,
         'A4': 0,
         'B1': 7,
         'B2': 36,
         'B3': 8,
         'B4': 2,
         'C1': 1,
         'C2': 50,
         'C3': 15,
         'C4': 7,
         'C5': 1,
         'D3': 4,
         'D4': 2,
         'D5': 1,
         'other': 862})
```